# Weblogic not clearing cache

Tags: caching, jakarta-ee, jar, weblogic, rhel

We have installed Weblogic 10.3.1.0 on a RHEL (linux) machine.
Recently a new version of an application was uploaded to the Weblogic. Unfortunately the new changes are not reflecting.
I am told by the environments team that they did clear the `/opt/BAE_Weblogic/WL_DOMAIN/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/our_application` folder before deploying.

I have checked the following folders and I don't see any old files there:

```
/tmp/_WL_user/AFM2.2.24M2/ths7y1/war
/tmp/_WL_user/AFM2.2.24M2/ths7y1/public
domains/DOMAIN/servers/AdminServer/cache
```

Is there something that I am missing.

Comment: Do you have managed servers as well?, Try deleting managed server tmp as well. What kind of changes are not reflecting? do delete the .wlnotdelete directory as well

Answer (score 3):

Don't delete the `tmp/_WL_user/appname/` directory *before* deploying a new version; delete it *after* the deployment, if needed.

Better yet, do things in writing / building your app so that the newer `WAR/EAR/JAR/TRUCK/BICYCLE` files only contain files with newer timestamps.

Even better still, there's a file that if it exists in either `WEB-INF` or `META-INF` (don't recall which) that when the first access after a redeploy occurs, WebLogic will see that file has a newer timestamp and will clobber all the cached crud automatically.  The trouble is, I don't recall what that filename is supposed to be (IIRC, it's in ALL CAPS, though).

Yet even better than that, rewrite the application(s) so that these aren't a problem.  Of the several hundred applications I run around here on WebLogic servers, only a very small number ever have this problem.  The vast majority of applications, "Just Work," when they are updated.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I just met with similar issue where I was not getting my new classes reflected during MDB call. I restarted the servers, deleted the deployables thought it could clear the cache, still the deployable folders were available in /tmp/_WL_user/*/war, /tmp/_WL_user/*/public, domains/DOMAIN/servers/AdminServer/cache, but with no luck.

But then I realized that by mistake I put those classes (OLD) in one of the jar. These classes were actually creating problem and I was thinking if weblogic is caching the files. Sounds a bit silly but this may help in case someone doing similar mistake :-)

Cheers,
Mayur